# php function called, jquery called, js called, but no actions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I am in a dead end.
I use that simple jQuery accordion code on my whole website. Everything works fine. Jquery is loaded and my script as well in the `<header>`

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

  //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
  $('.titre-accordeon').click(function() {

    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('.titre-accordeon').removeClass('on');

    //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
    $('.contenu-accordeon').slideUp('normal');

    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

      //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
      $(this).addClass('on');

      //OPEN THE SLIDE
      $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     }      
   }); 
  $('.titre-accordeon').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');                    
  });
  $('.contenu-accordeon').hide();

});

  })(jQuery);
```

To call some listings I've made a simple php function like this

```
<?php
function ajouterListe($l, $c){
    ?>
    <div class="titre-accordeon"><?php echo $l ;?></div>
    <div class="contenu-accordeon"><?php echo $c ;?></div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

that I call like this

```
<?php ajouterListe($l, $c);?>
// $l & $c are well defined
```

**I have no error, the list displays but the javascript doesn't work !!!**
On the console side, everything is fine. js loaded and div well displayed with the right classes .titre-accordeon & .contenu-accordeon ... I click and no action.

Everywhere else my script works well. Is there something wrong with my JS?

Snippet for convenience

```js
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

  //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
  $('.titre-accordeon').click(function() {

    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('.titre-accordeon').removeClass('on');

    //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
    $('.contenu-accordeon').slideUp('normal');

    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

      //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
      $(this).addClass('on');

      //OPEN THE SLIDE
      $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     }      
   }); 
  $('.titre-accordeon').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');                    
  });
  $('.contenu-accordeon').hide();

});

  })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="titre-accordeon">Test 1</div>
<div class="contenu-accordeon">Test 2</div>
```

Comment: As you can see from the snippet I added, everything seems to be working fine. So I'm really not sure how to reproduce your issue. Any parts you may be overlooking? Like other events on outer elements that prevent your handler to run?

Comment: Can you share final HTML doing a 'View Source' on the page? We might be able to help you with that info at hand.

Comment: Can you check the value here: if($(this).next().is(':hidden')...   Is this "true" every time or it can be "false"?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca , DeadLock it seems to be due to my structure (I have a .load function) $("#x").load("y.php"); Unfortunately if nothing is wrong with my js I don't think you can help me. If it's due to the complexity of the architecture I have to debug by my own. Thanks guys for having double checking my js =)

Comment: The HTML and the JS code is working. You may have some PHP issue. I create a static HTML file with the JS you have and it opens the "Test2" after click on the previous "Test1".
Does there any other JS which unbind the ".titre-accordeon" clicks?

Comment: If you only load those elements into your document after document.ready has already fired, then of course it did not find them at the point where you tried to attach the event handlers. Go read up on __event delegation__, it is the easy and elegant solution to that kind of problem.

Comment: @CBroe I'm aware of that. But as it is not my structure I had to investigate and take in consideration that maybe i had a problem with my JS. That's not the case. I've replaced the .(load) by some php include() and that creates other problems =)))))) What a wasted day. Thanks mate